# Python: Prevent argument array being globally modified

Tags: python

I have a problem with python here. If I pass an array through a recursive function that adds something to the array each time it is called, the array is modified in each instance

**Code:**

```
def test(n,myList):
    if n>0:
        myList.append("Test")
        print ( "BEFORE CALL Instance ", n, myList )
        test(n-1,myList)
        print ( "AFTER CALL Instance ", n, myList )
    else:
        return
```

Execution via `test(5,[])`

**Results:**

```
BEFORE CALL Instance  5 ['Test']
BEFORE CALL Instance  4 ['Test', 'Test']
BEFORE CALL Instance  3 ['Test', 'Test', 'Test']
BEFORE CALL Instance  2 ['Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test']
BEFORE CALL Instance  1 ['Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test']
AFTER CALL Instance  1 ['Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test']
AFTER CALL Instance  2 ['Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test']
AFTER CALL Instance  3 ['Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test']
AFTER CALL Instance  4 ['Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test']
AFTER CALL Instance  5 ['Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test']
```

Actual problem:

Each child function is modifying the array in all parent functions. How can I prevent this?

Copying the list into a new one and modifying it results in the same output as above

```
myListNew=myList
myListNew.append("Test")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempted solution does not actually copy the array.  It assigns a new name to the same array.  If you want to create a new array, try this:

```
my_new_list = my_list[:]
```

That creates a list containing a slice of the old list, where the slice starts at the beginning, and ends at the end.  In other words, a perfect copy of the list.

Comment: Is there some workaround on doing this on arrays (dictionaries) too? it says "unhashable type".

Comment: Check out the copy module in the library:  `another_d = copy.copy(d)`.  Or try `another_d = dict(d)`.

Comment: @sberry2A  That works perfectly.  My preference would be to do it *inside* test, to follow the general principle of not changing the data your caller provides.  Then you don't have to worry about copying whenever you call `test()`.  IOW, let them call `test(n-1, myList)`, and then do `newlist = mylist[:]` right away inside, and do all work on `newlist`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `copy.deepcopy()` to return a non-linked list. This also works for nested lists and dicts.